# How to change the disk signature of a raw image?

Tags: boot, grub, dd, mbr

I am talking about disk signatures in context of the [MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record). The area from 440 to 444 bytes.

Let's say I got a bootable raw image (bootable in a virtual machine).

How can I set the disk signature to a fixed (non-random) value while keeping the raw image bootable? How to automate (script) that?

(If you are wondering if that is useful and for what... It is useful in context of [verifiable builds](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Verifiable_Builds).)

Comment: reading wikipedia, doesn't the disk signature start at byte 441, so the 441st byte?

Comment: You tell me. ;-)

Comment: lol ok I was a bit annoyed by myself and not believing I had done this old mistake again. It is. They start counting with 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take your image, extract the first sector:

```
dd if=image of=mbr.dat bs=512 count=1
```

write "AAAAA" to position 440-444 and do not truncate the file:

```
echo -en "\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41" | dd of=mbr.dat conv=notrunc seek=440 bs=1
```

Use a hexeditor like okteta to verify that it did what you wanted. Then write it back:

```
dd if=mbr.dat of=image conv=notrunc
```

See my wikiblog http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/dd

Comment: Will it still be bootable? Can "modify dump.dat" be automated(scripted)?

Comment: yes using the command base64, more to come

Comment: You can use `xxd -r` to automate hex edits. For example `echo "A: 00" | xxd -r - test.img` writes `0x00` to position `0xA` in `test.img`.

Comment: completely edited it, now I am using dd's seek function to get to position 440